# i3 status bar: low battery not showing up in red

Tags: arch-linux, i3

I have configured this in my i3status.conf:

```
battery 0 {
  format = "%status %percentage - %remaining"
  low_threshold = 30
  threshold_type = time
  integer_battery_capacity = true
}
```

And the battery indicator works just fine, except for the fact that it does not turn red when under the low_threshold, which it should according to [the documentation](http://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html#_battery).

What can cause it not be become red? All other text is white.

Answer (score 1):

When working with the very basic i3status bar, your options are quite limited. Yet in this case I think your error is in saying `threshold_type = time`. This makes i3status display the text red if less than 30 minutes of power supply are remaining (see the [i3status-manpage](https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html)).

If instead you set `threshold_type` to `percentage` with a `low_threshold = 30` your battery text will appear read as it reaches 29% and below.

I hope this solves your or anyone's problem who looks up this page. I started with i3status as well, but can now recommend [Conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) as a good status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for writing many years later...

i3status seems to show in red only if the laptop isn't plugged. If it's charging, even if you are below the threshold, it shows white.

Or maybe the problem could be this:
Try putting `color_bad = "#FF0000"` inside `battery 0 {...}`.
If I had color_bad only inside `general {...}` didn't work... if I remember well.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon your question and noticed there were no replies so I thought I'd give it a whirl.

First off, I do not edit `/etc/i3status.conf`. Instead, I use conky and edit `~/.conkyrc`. By changing the `/etc/i3status.conf`, you are changing the system file, which will then make that setting system wide. Just add the following to your `~/.conkyrc` and it should work. You may have to change the path `/sys/class/power_suply/AC0/online` to cater to your system though.

```
${if_existing /sys/class/power_supply/AC0/online 0}
   ${if_match ${battery_percent} <= 20}
     {"full_text": "D ${battery_percent BAT0}%" , "color":"\#FB4646"},
   ${else}
     {"full_text": "D ${battery_percent BAT0}%" , "color":"\#909090"},
   ${endif}
${else}
   ${if_match ${battery_percent} <= 20}
     {"full_text": " ${battery_percent BAT0}%" , "color":"\#FB4646"},
   ${else}
     {"full_text": " ${battery_percent BAT0}%" , "color":"\#909090"},
   ${endif}
${endif}
```

Hope this solves your question, although I hope you have already solved it.